# States are changing after API call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to change state before it fetch data from API, but I tried to debug and found out that states are changing after it hit API but I have placed code before try block. I will use this data in FlatList component.

Here is the code:

```
changeState = (s) => {
    this.setState(
      {
        status: s,
        page: 0,
        data: [],
      },
      () => {
        console.log(this.state.status);
      },
    );
  };

  getData = async (del) => {
    if (del == true) {
      this.setState({
        data: [],
      });
    } else if (del == 'active') {
      this.changeState(true);
    } else if (del == 'past') {
      this.changeState(false);
    }
    const newPage = this.state.page + 1;

    try {
      console.log(newPage, this.state.status, this.state.data);
      let orders = await api.getUserOrders(
        this.props.user.userID,
        this.state.limit,
        newPage,
        this.state.status,
      );

      this.setState({
        order: orders,
      });
      this.setState({
        data: [...this.state.data, ...this.state.order.results],
        // data: orders.results,
        isLoading: false,
        fetchingStatus: true,
        setOnLoad: true,
        page: newPage,
      });
    } catch (err) {
      Alert.alert(JSON.stringify(err));
      this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
      });
    }
  };
```

Comment: You are `await`ing the API call which by definition means that any code after that won't run till that API call resolves. It doesn't make any sense to do it earlier because you can't possible have `orders` available before the API request resolves, since you are getting it from the API.

Comment: @RobinZigmond I want to run changeState function before the API call so if user change the order status to "Past" so it should change state of status to false and page 0 and data blank [] .

Comment: so any state you want to set before the API call, do in a `setState` call *before* the `let orders = await ...` line. Any that should happen when the API request has completed, go after that line.

Comment: @RobinZigmond tried, didn't work though